# Pass multiple radio button group values to controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-group

I have a situation that I need to display list of radio button groups (based on modules) and user to choose the access level (say No access, Read access, Full access).
The model I have as:

```
public class Module
{
    public string AccessLevel{get;set;}
    public string ModuleName{get;set;}
}

public class UserData
{
    public List<Module> AllModules{get;set;}
}
```

In CSHTML, something like:

```
foreach (var n in Model.AllModules)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.AccessLevel, @n.ModuleName + "_N")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.AccessLevel, @n.ModuleName + "_R")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.AccessLevel, @n.ModuleName + "_F")
}
```

On submit, how can I get the user opted values? Also I am not getting the right values selected while  loading.

Comment: Why are you appending extra text to the value `.. @n.ModuleName + "_N"`? If the first `ModuleName` is say "Module1", then instead of returning "Module1" your setting the value of `AccessLevel` to "Module1_N". Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: I thought of it to differentiate the value of the radio button in  case if I need to manipulate anything in client side?

Comment: Your not actually doing that anyway (second parameter sets the `value` attribute, which are alreay unique). If you want to add an `id` for use in an associated label (best practice) or to use in javascript/jquery then you need to use the overload that accepts `htmlAttributes`

Comment: Also by doing this you have lost server to client binding. If the value of `AccessLevel` is "Module1" then the first radio button should be selected, but because you don't have a radio button with `value="Module1"`, no radio button will be selected.